# how to get clicked li hightlighted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am trying to access the `key={1}` Element on my li.
What i am trying to achive is to set the activeItem in State, to compare it later with the clicked one. I they are the same i want to add an active class to that element. But i cant find a way to geht the key passed into my handleClick function.

Thanks for your help.

```
import Link from 'next/link';

class Navbar extends React.Component {

  state = { activeItem: null}

  handleClick = (e) => {


  };

    render() {
    console.log(this.state)
      return (
      <nav className="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Kategories
          <span className="arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
        </a>
        <ul className="submenu">
          <li 
              onClick={this.handleClick}
              key={1}
          >
              <Link href={`/news?cat=sport`} ><a>Sport</a></Link>
          </li>
          <li>
          <Link href={`/news?cat=health`}><a>Health</a></Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <style jsx>{`




.main-nav {
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    z-index:100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 23px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 23px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 23px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.main-nav a {
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: lato;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background 0.4s;
  }

  .main-nav a:hover {
    background: #b4d455;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }


  .main-nav a:hover .arrow{
    color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(0);

  }

  .main-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
  }

  .main-nav li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }

  .main-nav li:hover .submenu > li {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    top: 0px;
  }

  .submenu li {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
  }

  .submenu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .submenu li {
    position: relative;
  }

  .submenu li:hover .submenu-2 li {
    display: block;
  }


  .arrow {
    margin-left: 8px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 10px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

  .active {
    background-color: red;
  }

    `}

    </style>
  </nav>
  );
  }



}

export default Navbar;
```

thank you for the answer. It works . But i am not sure if this is the best way. The data-key is not dynamic at the moment and i am not sure how to get the value in the ternary.

```
state = { activeItem: null}



  handleClick = e => {

    this.setState({ activeItem : e.currentTarget.dataset.key })
    };

    render() {
      return (
      <nav className="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Kategories
          <span className="arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
        </a>
        <ul className="submenu">
          <li className={this.state.activeItem == 1 ? 'active' : ''}
              onClick={this.handleClick}
              data-key={1}
          >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set it as `data-key={1}` you can have access to that with `e.currentTarget.dataset`.

If you log it like this:

```
handleClick = e => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset);
};
```

You should get the following result:

[image]

Comment: as you can see above i tried to get it to work. Unfrtunatelly it doesnt work as expected. For some reason the the render method gets called twice and overrides itself on the first click.Any ides why it behaves like that?